# The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement Google Map in android  using Google API, but I am getting the error

> The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity

the whole `MainActivity` code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Fragments were available from Honey Comb onwards and hence your **target API shall >= 11**

If you want to use fragments to older versions of android you shall use android **support v7** library. And in that case your MainActivity shall extend **ActionBarActivity**, instead of Activity.

If you are using android **support v4**, your MainActivity shall extend **FragmentActivity** and you will need to call **getSupportFragmentManager()** instead of **getFragmentManager()**

I hope it helps!

Comment: "If you are using android support v4, your MainActivity shall extend FragmentActivity." This line helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `getFragmentManager()` you need to extend `FragmentActivity` not `Activity` like

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap map;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this import

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
```

And add this annotation before the onCreate method

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

Hope this will help !