# Is it possible to call FragmentManager from ActionProvider?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

How to call FragmentManager in onMenuItemClick?
I want to launch a dialog after user clicks on the sub-menu item.

I've tried to use:

```
Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;
```

But it causes error

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

```
public class StudentFilterActionProvider extends ActionProvider implements MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
Context mContext;

/**
 * Creates a new instance.
 *
 * @param context Context for accessing resources.
 */
public StudentFilterActionProvider(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateActionView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean hasSubMenu() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPrepareSubMenu(SubMenu subMenu) {
    // Only add item once, not every time the sub menu is clicked
    if (subMenu.size() == 0) {
        subMenu.add("Filter by status").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        subMenu.add("Filter by programme").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getTitle().toString()) {
        case "Filter by status":
            StudentStatusDialogFragment studentStatusDialogFragment = new StudentStatusDialogFragment();
            // I want to get FragmentManager here to launch a dialog
            return true;
        case "Filter by programme":
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why not just changing your code to

```
Activity mContext;

/**
 * Creates a new instance.
 *
 * @param context Context for accessing resources.
 */
public StudentFilterActionProvider(Activity context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}
```

Comment: Even that I still couldn't call getFragmentManager

Comment: Then make your context of type `FragmentActivity`. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21249790/4795214

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, FragmentActivity is used for support.v4

Comment: Try `ActionBarActivity`